# android xml tag strings combine

Tags: android, android-layout

how to connect two strings?

```
<TextView android:text="@string/app_name.@string/app_version" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/Welcome" android:textSize="34px"></TextView>
```

android:text="@string/app_name.@string/app_version"

the emulator directly printed "@string/app_name.@string/app_version" instead of the string
it supposed to be something like "APP 1.2"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't do that, if you want to use two strings in your TextView, you'd have to set the text programmatically:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);
tv.setText(getString(R.string.app_name) + getString(R.string.app_version));
```

Comment: so, it's not possible via xml, or it's just the syntax that doesn't support this kind of usage?